# preserving Member IDs on first import?

Tags: civimember, data-import

I have a list of members that I'm importing from our old system. Since they have unique numeric member numbers, I'd like to preserve the original member number and not muddy the waters by making that an 'External ID'.

Using import memberships, the insert option doesn't allow me to assign member IDs. the update option fails because the member IDs don't exist.

Thoughts on how to preserve the original membership IDs? Or am I out of luck?

Keith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We created a custom field to import it in so we had them on file, then as members renewed we switched over to using their contact ID's as member numbers and put a notice in their renewal emails that they would notice changes.

Comment: Does seem to be the only realistic approach. I have given up trying to force the old values in and settled for 'external id'